# Jenkins - before build email trigger with build_user_id

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Using *Jenkins 2.277.2* (LTS) and *Extended E-mail Notification* and *build user vars* plugins I'm trying to send emails **before** build to notify build-user that job is started and also after success/fail.

Problem is that I need to use `${BUILD_USER_ID}` variable and it does not get exposed for *Before Build* trigger. For any other triggers that I tested (*always*, *failure - any*, *success*) it is exposed correctly, however all of those emails are being sent after the build, and I need to notify build-user that job is started.

Any ideas how to achieve that? Ideally without any more plugins installation, but if there's no way - that's kind of acceptable too.
Thanks.

**upd** It'd probably be easier for me to illustrate what I meant - here's how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl5NR.png

Comment: For EMail user notification I'd use requestor()... did you try that? See https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/

Comment: I need to have that user id (login basically) in subject of a mail.
Mail itself is being sent to the right person, as I'm using GUI editor and simply chose "send to - build user"

It'd probably be easier for me to illustrate what I meant - here's how it looks https://i.imgur.com/YdG1N9C.png

Comment: Sure the build-user-vars plugin is installed? https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/ It's not installed by default. Documentation looks like the vars should be available immediately.

Comment: Of course I'm sure, as I said in original post - this exact variable is used in same jenkins job with other email triggers (always, failure - any, success) and it does gets expanded correctly. Its only 'before build' trigger where it doesn't work. Plugin itself is installed (https://i.imgur.com/BPpNuMr.png) and updated to latest version.